# is Data Retrieval language(DRL) a real term? Or it is just used for understanding

Tags: sql, oracle

Data Query Language consist of commands such as `select * from test`. But according to oracle docs, select command comes under Data Manipulation Language. So does Data Retrieval Language is an actual term in SQL?

P.S. When searched in SO tags, DRL does not show up here also :P

Comment: Why down votes?? whats wrong with the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been using oracle for 20 years and we use the DML and DDL (data definition language) acronyms a lot. I've heard DQL used but very rarely; it is just a select or a query. I've never heard the acronym DRL.

Also you might want to google these for combinations of DQL and DML:

> SIUD or CRUD

:p to you back :)

Comment: Thanks for the help :)